# SQL where exists returns empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to load up all the available operators in my db. Available meaning they are currently done with whatever job they were assigned and are available for new assignments.

I am querying the operators and jobs table, then joining the users table for their detail for this but i keep getting an empty result. 
Here's my code

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * from operator
 WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM job
      WHERE
      job.OperatorId = operator.OperatorId 
        AND job.Status == 'Completed') 
 INNER JOIN users ON  operator.UserId = users.UserId";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
print_r($result1);
```

Operator Table

[image: Operator Table]

Job Table

[image: Job Table]

Please advice on what i'm doing wrong

Comment: $result1 = $conn->query($sql1)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: Any joins should occur prior to the where clause.

Comment: `SELECT [...] FROM [...] WHERE [...] INNER JOIN [...]` isn't valid. Try `SELECT [...] FROM [...] INNER JOIN [...] WHERE [...]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql, the query need to be write like this :

```
SELECT [...]
FROM [...]
JOIN [...]
WHERE[...]
```

Then :

```
SELECT * from operator
INNER JOIN users ON  operator.UserId = users.UserId
 WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM job
      WHERE
      job.OperatorId = operator.OperatorId 
        AND job.Status == 'Completed')
```

Should work.

Comment: I've implemented this change but i'm still getting an empty result returned.

Comment: I have added how the tables look. Any idea what's making it behave this way?